# Nautilus opens with hidden files

Tags: unity, nautilus, files

As the title says, every time when I open Nautilus from unity launcher, it opens with all files being shown. Normally it opens with hidden files being hidden, how can I change it back to that behavior?

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity, no other WM/DM's are installed.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the option Show hidden and backup files in the Edit -> Prefererences. Just clear the checkbox and the hidden files will stay hidden after you re-open the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @Mikolaj Bartnicky's answer, you can use shortcut key `Ctrl+H` to show/hide the hidden files in Nautilus. It is same with `Alt+.` in Dolphin and Konqueror.

Comment: They won't stay hidden.